# What does the NC in WM_NCCREATE stand for?

Tags: windows, winapi

On Windows, the system sends the `WM_NCCREATE` window message followed by the `WM_CREATE` window message. While [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289196/) explains the difference in their purpose, neither it nor [the official MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-nccreate) explains a very basic thing: What does the `NC` in `WM_NCCREATE` stand for?

Comment: [About windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-windows) covers this in excruciating detail.

Answer (score 0):

The NC in WM_NCCREATE stands for "non-client." The non-client area of a window in a Windows application is the application icon, menu bar, title bar, minimize/maximize/close buttons, and resizeable border. I.e. the parts of the window that the system draws. The [WM_NCCREATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-nccreate) window message is sent prior to the [WM_CREATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-create) message when a window is first created.